# How come this JAX-RS 404 response gets an empty body?

Tags: jax-rs

I'm having trouble with a JAX-RS resource. Somehow I'm unable to set text/plain body when returning 404 (Response.Status.NOT_FOUND) to my custom plain text message "File not found". It works for almost every other response code I've tested. Body is empty in Postman/Chrome. Am I missing out on something here? PS. Using JAX-RS through [Helidon.io](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/webserver/07_jersey-support).

```
@Path("/")
public class FileResource {

@GET
@Path("{path}")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getFile(@PathParam("path") String path) {
    File file = new File(path+"/file.xml");
    if (file.exists()) {
      return Response.ok((Object) file).build();
    }
    //Following two returns work (ie. provides correct "File not Found" body):
    //return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).entity("File not found").type("text/plain").build();
    //return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("File not found ").type("text/plain").build();

    //...but THIS return does not work (results in 404 but with empty body) How come?:
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("File not found").type("text/plain").build();
}   
}
```